# Angular 2/4 redux framework

Tags: ngrx

Can you tell me what is the difference between ng-redux vs ngrx-store library in angular? I want to implement redux in my application but not sure which library to use and what are the benefits?

Comment: ng-redux is a library / ngrx is a profile containing multiple github repos

Comment: can you elaborate on that. i thought ngrx-store is angular implementation of redux pattern using rxjs. If yes, i want to know how is it different from ng-redux? Is it better or worst?

Comment: check this https://reduxsimplified.blogspot.com/2018/08/redux-introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

They both implement centralized state for your front-end, but I'd use ngrx/store for an Angular 2 app, because:

- ngrx is built on RxJS, which is also the basis for Angular 2's http module; This allows for various possibilities for interacting with your components like `store` && `dispatcher` through RxJS methods like filter, transform data... I also thought it was nice having the `Observable` pattern implemented uniformly for all my data logic. *`RxJS observables provide a more robust manner to interact with data related actions`*
- One method I thought was particularly cool was `select(key)` on the store module, which selects the specified state key and returns an observable that can be shared from a centralized service to multiple components; This minimized store subscription from components themselves and allowed for easy state updates from `container(stateful)` to `component(stateless)` leveraging Angular 2's change detection and `async` pipe.